# Possible race condition? Swift 2 iOS app randomly doesn't call func tableView(tableView

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview

I am developing an app that takes user input (a 8-10 digit number), and POSTs it to a php script, which in turn queries a database and returns results as JSON.

I parse the JSON and save the values into arrays, then load those arrays into a tableView.

The user hits search, which introduces a segue to a new view (via a Nav controller), the JSON data is sent to the table view, inside viewDidLoad() I parse the JSON and save it in arrays, and in func tableView I read values from the arrays into the rows, then return the cell.

My issues is that sometimes the data does not load in the rows, although the arrays always get filled, I get a blank tableview, I click back and try the search again, and it works.... for a few times then randomly stops.

I do have the delegate and data source clicked for the table view. I added the HTTP exception in the plist.

This is my first ever project, so any tips are appreciated. I am suspecting my code placement might be an issue causing a race condition? since I parse JSON in the viewDidLoad() function?

Code:

```
import UIKit

class ResultsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {


@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var ccnit = ""
var cunsArray : [String] = []
var accountsArray : [String] = []
var statusArray : [String] = []
var typesArray : [String] = []
var assignedArray : [String] = []



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    //establish connection
    let url = NSURL(string: "http:IPADDRESS/App/query.php")
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:url!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    request.HTTPBody = ccnit.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        data, response, error in

        if error != nil {
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }
        //print("response = \(response)")

       // let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
        //print("responseString = \(responseString)")



        //parse JSON

        do {

            let jsonArray = try (NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers)) as! NSArray

            //loop through json array and take out strings
            var counter = 0
            while counter < jsonArray.count{
                let cun = jsonArray[counter]["ticket_no"] as? String
                self.cunsArray.append(cun!)

                let account = jsonArray[counter]["accountname"] as? String
                self.accountsArray.append(account!)             

                let status = jsonArray[counter]["status"] as? String
                self.statusArray.append(status!)

                let type = jsonArray[counter]["category"] as? String
                self.typesArray.append(type!)

                let assigned_to = jsonArray[counter]["assigned_to"] as? String
                self.assignedArray.append(assigned_to!)

                counter = counter + 1
            }

            if (self.cunsArray.count > 0)
            {
                print("cunsArray has \(self.cunsArray.count) items")
            }
            if (self.accountsArray.count > 0)
            {
                print("accountsArray has \(self.accountsArray.count) items")
            }

            print("Finished populating arrays")
            self.tableView.delegate = self
            self.tableView.dataSource = self

        } catch let err {
            print(err)
        }

    }
    task.resume()


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return cunsArray.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell
    //print("*****inside tableview func")
    print("returning cells")
    //  cell.account.text = ""
    cell.cun.text = cunsArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.account.text = accountsArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.status.text = statusArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.type.text = typesArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.assigned_to.text = assignedArray[indexPath.row] 

    return cell
}
}
```

Comment: No one can help you fix your code if you don't post the relevant code.

Comment: code added, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like an issue with background threading:

```
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request)
```

is probably on the background thread internally and then you are setting the table datasource / delegate on the same thread.

Try swapping:

```
        self.tableView.delegate = self
        self.tableView.dataSource = self
```

with

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {() -> Void in
        self.tableView.delegate = self
        self.tableView.dataSource = self
 })
```

EDIT:

As [Jeremy Herrero](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2853002/jeremy-herrero) stated the datasource / delegate may have been added on storyboard level if so the correct solution would be:

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {() -> Void in
            self.tableView.reloadData()
     })

Comment: Fantastic! thanks a lot @SeanLintern88. I added the dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {() -> Void in self.tableView.reloadData() }) inside the getData() and got rid of the delegate/ data source calls and it works!

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't pack so much into viewDidLoad. Also you need to call reloadData() once you have your data or else the tableView will not refresh. The only time you do not need to call reloadData() is when your data is available at the time of the tableView's creation.

In the future, keep your code clean and well formatted. That will help you more than anything. Sloppy code will lead to sloppy results and endless future headaches.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.dataSource = self

    getData()
}

func getData() {
    let url = NSURL(string: "http:IPADDRESS/App/query.php")
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:url!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    request.HTTPBody = ccnit.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        data, response, error in

        if error != nil {
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }

        do {
            let jsonArray = try (NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers)) as! NSArray
            var counter = 0
            var accounts = []
            while counter < jsonArray.count {
                let cun = jsonArray[counter]["ticket_no"] as? String
                self.cunsArray.append(cun!)

                let account = jsonArray[counter]["accountname"] as? String
                self.accountsArray.append(account!)

                let status = jsonArray[counter]["status"] as? String
                self.statusArray.append(status!)

                let type = jsonArray[counter]["category"] as? String
                self.typesArray.append(type!)

                let assigned_to = jsonArray[counter]["assigned_to"] as? String
                self.assignedArray.append(assigned_to!)

                counter = counter + 1
            }

            if (self.cunsArray.count > 0) {
                print("cunsArray has \(self.cunsArray.count) items")
            }
            if (self.accountsArray.count > 0) {
                print("accountsArray has \(self.accountsArray.count) items")
            }

            tableView.reloadData()

        } catch let err {
            print(err)
        }

    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: Technically he doesnt have to call reloadData() he is setting his delegate/datasource after getting the data which automatically reloads the table.

Comment: Interesting. I've never tried that before. It sounded like he may have hooked up the delegate and datasource in the storyboard as well. Wonder if that would have affected it if the code was redundant?

Comment: True if he has set it up in storyboard too then reloadData() would be his solution although I believe this is a threading issue.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. However, reloading the data and moving the code did not help. I still get blank results randomly. Yes the delegate and data source are set in the storyboard

Answer (score 0):

You should call reloadData (in the main thread) after loading the data

```
...
print("Finished populating arrays")
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
   self.tableView.reloadData()
});
...
```